# Devise and routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise to authenticate users and getting the following error at registration and sign in pages

```
No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"devise/home"}
```

Apparently it's caused by

```
<%= link_to "Search", url_for(:controller => "home", :action => "search")
```

in layouts/application.html.erb

The setup is absolutely basic, here's routes.rb:

```
get "home/search"
devise_for :users
root :to => "home#index"
```

Comment: Quick and dirty fix is to add slash before controller name, url_for(:controller => "/home", :action => "search"). The other way around is to use resource routes.

Answer (score 1):

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to:

> Be careful when using the older
>   argument style, as an extra literal
>   hash is needed:

```
link_to "Articles", { :controller => "articles" }, :id => "news", :class => "article"
# => <a href="/articles" class="article" id="news">Articles</a>
```

> Leaving the hash off gives the wrong
>   link:

```
link_to "WRONG!", :controller => "articles", :id => "news", :class => "article"
# => <a href="/articles/index/news?class=article">WRONG!</a>
```

It is considered "preferable" to use named resource routes as described in the link above so that if your resource routes change, you don't have to manually update your links.